# Best way to sort through a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, polymorphic-associations, nested-attributes

So - having the following setup:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :invitations
end

class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guest, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :event
end

class Member > ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invitations, :as => :guest

  def full_name
    [first_name, last_name].join(" ")
  end
end

class Visitor > ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invitations, :as => :guest

  def full_name
    name
  end
end
```

In the end, I want to be able to fetch an Events invitations **ordered by the Guests full_name**. I can't figure out how - anyone who can help me solve this? Would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I think you can do it only with Ruby not with sql because of polymorphic structure

Comment: I'm guessing you're right! Any suggestions how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as `full_name` is a virtual attributes I can imagine only ruby solution, not sql

```
event = Event.find some event
event.invitations.sort_by(&:full_name)
```

Comment: Is there a similar option for `order()`. For example in the index action `Model...joins()...order()...paginate`? Or would order only take the one table column?

Comment: @Sash something like this in mysql `Event.order("concat(first_name, last_name) DESC")`

Comment: Awesome! I also found `.order('COALESCE(column_a, column_b) DESC')` super useful.